# Linked list implementation in c, run time error

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

There is no error when I compile the code, but the program crashes at runtime after two inputs. Maybe there is some logical error that I can not make out. I'm trying to insert nodes at the tail of linked lists while only maintaining head position.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{

    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *head;

//print the element of the lists
void print(){
    printf("\nThe list from head to tail is as follows \n");
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("\n %d ",(*temp).data);
        temp = (*temp).next;
    }
}

//insert a node at the tail of the linked list
void insert_at_tail(int data){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data=data;
    new_node->next=NULL;

    if(temp==NULL){
        head=new_node;
    }
    else{
        while(temp!=NULL){temp=temp->next;}
        (*temp).next=new_node;
    }
}
int main(){

    head = NULL;
    int i,data;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%d",&data);
        insert_at_tail(data);
    }
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe there is some logical error?

Yes!

Here:

```
while(temp!=NULL) { temp=temp->next; }
(*temp).next=new_node;
```

you will loop until `temp` is actually `NULL` and then request its `next` member, so you are asking for `next` of `NULL`, thus you are asking for trouble (the program crashes)!

Try doing this instead:

```
while(temp->next != NULL) { temp=temp->next; }
```

where you are looping until `temp` points to the *last* node of your list. With that change your code should work fine.

---

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: while(temp!=NULL){temp=temp->next;}
temp=new_node;  this worked.

Comment: @EshanPandey I think you should follow my solution, since I tested it works nicely. Your approach doesn't connect the nodes.

Comment: It is not like I did not like your solution, just that I came up with my own. Obviously, your answer helped. You pointed out what I was doing wrong, which helped me. @gsamaras Thanks. BTW still struggling with print() function.

Comment: Yes because you **do not link the nodes**. The `next` member of every node of yours points to `NULL` with your solution, while with mine's, every node points to its next node. That's why you can't print your list @EshanPandey.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. My approach does not connect the nodes and therefore the entire list is not printed.. only 1st element. But I don't understand this completely. Can you help (explain)

Comment: Thanks.. @gsamaras got it now.

Comment: @EshanPandey get a piece of paper and **draw** what your code does, that will help! With your approach the `next` member of every node points to `NULL`, thus when you try to print the list (thus iterate over it), you ask for the `next` member, which is `NULL`, thus your first node thinks that it is the last as well (because it's `next` is `NULL` incorrectly!).